# Group theory : prove $G = \lbrace a^{-1}\alpha(a) \; |\; a \in G\rbrace$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a finite group, and $\alpha \in Aut(G)$ such that $\alpha(a) = a \Longleftrightarrow a = 1$.

Show that $G = \lbrace a^{-1}\alpha(a) \; |\; a \in G\rbrace$.

It is obvious that $\lbrace a^{-1}\alpha(a) \; |\; a \in G \rbrace \subseteq G$, but I have problems with proving that $G \subseteq \lbrace a^{-1}\alpha(a) \; |\; a \in G \rbrace$. I know that $\alpha$ is surjective function because it is in Aut(G), and because of its property it will be true, but I don't know how I can write and prove in mathematics. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Hint: You can prove injectivity instead.  Suppose that $a_1^{-1}\alpha(a_1)=a_2^{-1}\alpha(a_2)$ and use the properties of homomorphisms to prove that $a_1=a_2$.  If this hint doesn't help enough, let me know and I'll give a longer answer.

Comment: you mean : you want to prove that every elements in $\lbrace a^{-1}\alpha(a)\; | \; a \in G\rbrace$ are different and you prove by contradiction ? and how to prove $a_1 = a _2$ with homomorphism?

Comment: You want to prove that the map $a\mapsto a^{-1}\alpha(a)$ is injective, so $|\{a^{-1}\alpha(a):a\in G\}|=|G|$.  Since it is a subset, you then have equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch: Suppose that $a_1^{-1}\alpha(a_1)=a_2^{-1}\alpha(a_2)$.  Then, by rearranging, we have that $\alpha(a_1)\alpha(a_2)^{-1}=a_1a_2^{-1}$.  Then, by using properties of homomorphisms, $\alpha(a_1a_2^{-1})=a_1a_2^{-1}$.  Hence, by assumption, $a_1a_2^{-1}=1$ so $a_1=a_2$.

Therefore, for each $a\in G$, $a^{-1}\alpha(a)$ is different.  Hence $\{a^{-1}\alpha(a):a\in G\}$ has at least $|G|$ many elements.  Since it is a subset of $G$ (and $|G|$ is finite), it must equal $G$.

Comment: you are right,Thanks so much for your nice solution !